# How can I adjust the format of visuals for Power BI Mobile View?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I'm using Power BI to create a report using a slicer and a pie chart. Because the desktop view affords me so much screen real estate, I increased the font sizes on my visuals.

When I switch to the mobile view, it allows me to include defined visuals (slicer, pie chart), but there is no option available to format them differently for the mobile view, at least not one that I can find. Does one exist?

If not, what is the workaround for this? Do I have to create a duplicate of the visual and somehow hide it (I don't know how to hide visuals)?

Answer (score 0):

I would return the font sizes back to the defaults or thereabouts. These give the best results when your content is consumed on a range of devices.